# How can I show Azure Metrics for all VMs that match a Resource Query

Tags: azure-monitoring

I am building a workbook where I would like to show metrics, e.g. CPU load for a set of VMs that dynamically change over time. I can see how I can add a metric, but in the editor I am forced to pick one of the currently running VMs. I would like to use a Resource Query and list the desired metric for all VMs that match the criteria.

I see how this nicely works for logs, where the scope can be determined by a resource query, but my data is not sitting in logs, but metrics. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Azure Monitor Workbook to display Azure Metrics for all VMs that match a Resource Query. Here are the general steps to follow:

1. In the Azure portal, go to the Azure Monitor service and open the Workbooks page.
2. Click on "Create a workbook" to create a new workbook.
3. In the "Select a data source" pane, choose "Metrics" as the data source.
4. In the "Metrics" pane, specify the Azure subscription and resource group that contains the VMs you want to monitor.
5. In the "Query" pane, enter a Kusto query that uses the resource query language to select all VMs that match your criteria. For example, you could use a query like this to select all VMs in a specific resource group:

This query selects all resources of type "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" in the specified resource group.

```
where type == 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines' and resourceGroup == '<resource-group-name>'
```

6. In the "Visualization" pane, select the chart type you want to use (e.g. line chart, area chart, etc.) and specify the metric you want to display (e.g. "Percentage CPU" for the "Processor" metric category).
   7.Customize the chart by selecting the time range, aggregation type, and other options as per your requirement.
7. Save the workbook and share it with other users who need access to the data.

Once you have created the workbook, you can use it to monitor Azure Metrics for all VMs that match the specified Resource Query. The workbook will automatically update the charts based on the selected time range and aggregation type.

Comment: I can see a "Monitor" blade (not Azure Monitor), and when I create a workbook there, I can't find "Select a data source" pane, in the empty workbook settings I can only "select resources".  Where are these? Do you refer to the point where I am adding items to the workbook?

Comment: great answer! just out of curiosity, did you get this from chatgpt?